# Mokito crash when a mock return function, contain mocking function within?

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, mockito

When creating a test below

```
@Test
public void myTest() {
    MyRepo myRepo = Mockito.mock(MyRepo.class);
    when(myRepo.getMyItemList()).thenReturn(createMyItemList(3));
    // More Test verification
}

private List<MyItem> createMyItemList(int count) {

    List<MyItem> myItemList = new ArrayList<>();
    while (count > 0) {
        myItemList.add(createMyItem());
        count--;
    }
    return myItemList;
}

private MyItem createMyItem() {
    MyItemDetail myItemDetail = new MyItemDetail();
    ItemDetailGen itemDetailGen = Mockito.mock(ItemDetailGen.class);
    when(itemDetailGen.getItem()).thenReturn(myItemDetail);

    return new MyItem(itemDetailGen);
}
```

I got error on the line of `when(itemDetailGen...` when running it

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.UnfinishedStubbingException: 
Unfinished stubbing detected here:
-> at ...

E.g. thenReturn() may be missing.
Examples of correct stubbing:
    when(mock.isOk()).thenReturn(true);
    when(mock.isOk()).thenThrow(exception);
    doThrow(exception).when(mock).someVoidMethod();
Hints:
 1. missing thenReturn()
 2. you are trying to stub a final method, you naughty developer!
```

If I debug into it, the crash happens on `when(myRepo.getMyItemList...` instead.

Why is this problem?

It seems like a return of a mock function (i.e. `createMyItemList`), shouldn't contain another mock within. My temporary fix is remove the private function mock, by creating a new constructor for `MyItem` to directly accept MyItemDetail object as below, which is not ideal, since the actual code doesn't use that.

```
private MyItem createMyItem() {
   MyItemDetail myItemDetail = new MyItemDetail();
   return new MyItem(myItemDetail);
}
```

*UPDATED*
Just to make it clearer, I'm showing all the class (simplified) content.

```
class MyRepo {
    List<MyItem> myItemsList;
    List<MyItem> getMyItemList() {
        return myItemsList;
    }
    void addMyItemList(List<MyItem> myItemsList) {
        this.myItemsList = myItemsList;
    }
}

class MyItem {
    private MyItemDetail myItemDetail;
    public MyItem(ItemDetailGen itemDetailGen) {
        this.myItemDetail = itemDetailGen.getItem();
    }
    public MyItem(MyItemDetail myItemDetail) {
        this.myItemDetail = myItemDetail;
    }
}

class MyItemDetail {
}

class ItemDetailGen {
    MyItemDetail getItem() {
        return new MyItemDetail();
    }
}
```

Combine the class code and the test code, the entire test could be run to demonstrate the issue clearly.

Comment: Can you post the `ItemDetailGen` class, or at minimum the `getItem()` method?

Comment: Thanks. In actual, ItemDetailGen is a database Cursor, that will provide provide the information accordingly. But even if I simplify ItemDetailGen to a very simple class, as long as I mock it, the problem will be there. Hence it's not related to ItemDetailGen. When we trace the code run in debug, the mock of ItemDetailGen works perfectly without issue. It only crashes on ` when(myRepo.getMyItemList()).thenReturn(createMyItemList(3));`

Comment: Mostly wondering if either your class itself is final, or the `getItem()` method is final. As a side note, this shouldn't matter, but you don't need to add `@Mock` for a local variable -- that's only needed for fields if you're using `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks()` or using `MockitoJUnitRunner`.

Comment: What is `myRepo`? Is that class `final`? Is `myRepo.getMyItemList()` `final`?

Comment: Good question kcoppock. I should have stated that clearly. They are all NOT final. Else would have been a really easy fix. I have tried a global mock variable as well, and it still crash... then I try locally though the global can't be used as it has mutliple when.thenReturn needed.